# webapp doesn't exist with Azure CLI 2.0.79

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I have upgraded recently to 2.0.79 due to the problems with 2.0.78 caused with static HTML pages
I am following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-get-started-html) Microsoft tutorial but keep getting the error

> "webapp anotherwebapp doesn't exist"

when I enter the command:

```
 az webapp up --location westeurope --name anotherwebapp --html
```

The contents on the directory is listed below (dir):

```
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          .
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          ..
08/01/2020  08:27 PM             4,447 .gitignore
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          css
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          fonts
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          img
08/01/2020  08:27 PM             2,338 index.html
08/01/2020  08:27 PM    <DIR>          js
08/01/2020  08:27 PM             1,183 LICENSE
08/01/2020  08:27 PM               608 README.md
               4 File(s)          8,576 bytes
               6 Dir(s)  1,214,520,279,040 bytes free
```

Any help with resolving this would be much appreciated!

Comment: Hello @Lousis, What is the directory content? Can you provide dir/ls of where you are running this? So we can dig into it further.

Comment: @MonikaReddy-MSFT Thank you for your reply, please see my edit

Comment: Are you in the right Context/Subscription? Does the webapp "anotherwebapp" exist?

Comment: use `az account show` and `az webapp list` and check if they give the expected results

Comment: Sounds like this bug: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/11237

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please [accept it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top)? Thanks. And please let me know if you still have issues.

Answer (score 0):

First, are you sure "webapp anotherwebapp doesn't exist" is an error message? it should be a prompt since it actually does not exist.

I can successfully deploy it with 2.0.79, and the steps are as below:

1.Install [azure cli 2.0.79](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-windows?view=azure-cli-latest#install-or-update) via downloading the .msi, then restarts the machcine.

2.Then in cmd prompt, nav to the folder where my html project resides -> run the command:

```
az webapp up --location westeurope --name anotherwebapp111 --html
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

3.Nav to azure portal, I can see the site is deployed successfully.

[image]